# How to clean up aftermath from rookie ubuntu command

Tags: 12.04, permissions, sudo

Here are the commands I regretfully run:

`sudo chgrp root /usr/bin`
`sudo chgrp root /usr/local`

I had recently added a user to root group and because my user still did not have write permissions, I assumed I had to reapply the group setting to those directories (was originally `root` group).

That led to issues with `sudo` command, namely:

`sudo must be setuid root`

Which I've fixed. Then xubuntu wouldn't start, which I somehow fixed..now zsh is complaining:

`zsh compinit: insecure directories, run compaudit for list.`

My question is have I completely ruined this installation? If not, is there a way to fix the permissions?

Comment: did you happen to run those commands with the -R flag, or did you also run some chmod commands?  The chgrp on its own shouldn't have broken sudo, since those folders should already be owned by the root group.

Comment: @ImaginaryRobots I don't believe I did, but I can't fathom why that would have changed permissions on children (like zsh directory). I've since fixed the zsh issue, but I have a feeling I'm not going to understand the extent of the damage until I use my system for a bit longer.

Comment: A clean install would be the easiest way to make sure everything has the correct permissions and ownerships.

Answer (score 0):

To recover the permissions on the sudo executable, you'll need to boot to recovery mode and make the changes from there. Specifically:

- reboot your computer
- choose the "Ubuntu recovery" option - this will get you a root shell without needing sudo
- run the commands:

  chmod 755 /usr/bin/sudo

  chmod +s /usr/bin/sudo
- use ls to confirm that the permissions are okay now:

  ls -l /usr/bin/sudo
- the output should start with:

  -rwsr-xr-x 2 root root

At this point you can test sudo to see if it works as the root user:

```
sudo echo "it works"
```

If that works, then you can reboot to an ordinary ubuntu session and use sudo to fix whatever else needs fixing.